# Exercise about Schwarz derivative

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, differential

> If $f$ is three times differentiable and $f'(x)\neq 0$, the Schwarz derivative of $f$ at $x$ is defined by $$\mathscr{D}f(x)=\dfrac{f'''(x)}{f'(x)}-\dfrac32\left( \dfrac{f''(x)}{f'(x)}\right)^2.$$ (a) Demonstrate that $$\mathscr{D}(f\circ g)=[\mathscr{D}f\circ g]\cdot g'^2+\mathscr{D}g.$$

My solution: using the chain rule and the product rule and, we obtain

$$(f\circ g)'(x)=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$$
$$(f\circ g)''(x)=f''(g(x))\cdot (g'(x))^2+f'(g(x))\cdot g''(x)$$
$$(f\circ g)'''(x)=f'''(g(x))\cdot (g'(x))^3+2f''(g(x))\cdot g'(x)g''(x)+f''(g(x))\cdot g''(x)g'(x)+f'(g(x))\cdot g'''(x)=f'''(g(x))\cdot (g'(x))^3+3f''(g(x))\cdot g'(x)g''(x)+f'(g(x))\cdot g'''(x)$$

\begin{align*}
 \mathscr{D}(f\circ g) &= \dfrac{(f\circ g)'''(x)}{(f\circ g)'(x)}-\dfrac32\left( \dfrac{(f\circ g)''(x)}{(f\circ g)'(x)}\right)^2=\\
&= \dfrac{f'''(g(x))\cdot (g'(x))^3+3f''(g(x))\cdot g'(x)g''(x)+f'(g(x))\cdot g'''(x)}{f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)}-\dfrac32 \left( \dfrac{f''(g(x))\cdot (g'(x))^2+f'(g(x))\cdot g''(x)}{f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)}\right)^2 =\\
&= \dfrac{f'''(g(x))}{f'(g(x))}(g'(x))^2+3\dfrac{f''(g(x))}{f'(g(x))}g''(x)+\dfrac{g'''(x)}{g'(x)}-\dfrac32 \left( \left( \dfrac{f''(g(x))}{f'(g(x))}\right)^2(g'(x))^2+2\dfrac{f''(g(x))}{f'(g(x))}g''(x)+\left( \dfrac{g''(x)}{g'(x)}\right)^2\right)=\\
&= \left( \dfrac{f'''(g(x))}{f'(g(x))}-\dfrac32 \left( \dfrac{f''(g(x))}{f'(g(x))}\right) \right) (g'(x))^2+\left( \dfrac{g'''(x)}{g'(x)}-\dfrac32 \left( \dfrac{g''(x)}{g'(x)}\right)^2 \right) =[\mathscr{D}f\circ g]\cdot (g')^2+\mathscr{D}g
\end{align*}

> (b) Show that if $f(x)=\dfrac{ax+b}{cx+d}$, with $ad-bc\neq 0$, then $\mathscr{D}f=0$. Therefore, $\mathscr{D}(f\circ g)=\mathscr{D}g$.

My solution: $f(x)=\dfrac{ax+b}{cx+d}$, where $ad-bc\neq 0$.

We have $f(x)=\dfrac{a}{c}-\dfrac{ad-bc}{c(cx+d)}$.

We can find $f'$, $f''$, and $f'''$:

$$f'(x)=\dfrac{ad-bc}{(cx+d)^2}$$
$$f''(x)=-2c\cdot \dfrac{ad-bc}{(cx+d)^3}$$
$$f'''(x)=6c^2\cdot \dfrac{ad-bc}{(cx+d)^4}$$

Then we have $\dfrac{f'''(x)}{f'(x)}=\dfrac{6c^2}{(cx+d)^2}$ and $\dfrac{f''(x)}{f'(x)}=-\dfrac{2c}{cx+d}$.

$$\mathscr{D}f(x)=\dfrac{f'''(x)}{f'(x)}-\dfrac32\left( \dfrac{f''(x)}{f'(x)}\right)^2 =\dfrac{6c^2}{(cx+d)^2}-\dfrac32\dfrac{4c^2}{(cx+d)^2}=0$$

Therefore, $\mathscr{D}(f\circ g)=[\mathscr{D}f\circ g]\cdot (g')^2+\mathscr{D}g=0\cdot (g')^2+\mathscr{D}g=\mathscr{D}g$.

Is my solution correct? Anything to improve or comment on?

Comment: For the first part: proposition 3.2 of this [document](http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2020/REUPapers/Cooper.pdf) gives the same redult but with a simpler computation.

Comment: For the second part ("blindness" of Schwarzian derivative to homographies), see the fantastic answer of Bill Thurston [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/38125). This 1982 Fields medallist, who died recently, had a very nice expository style.

Comment: A very tiny detail : "Schwarz derivative" $\to$ "Schwarzian derivative"

Comment: Thank you very much! Fantastic answer of Bill Thurston!